# Microsoft SSIS Connectors by Attunity Version 4.0 NOT showing on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, ssis, attunity, ssis-2016

In one of our company meetings with Microsoft we were advised to use [Microsoft SSIS Connectors by Attunity Version 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52950) if we extract data from Oracle. We used to extract the data from Oracle using Oracle Provider for OLE DB.

I have tried to install the recommended components without success. I have oracle clients [32 bits](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html) (ODTwithODAC122010.zip) and [64 bits](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) (ODAC122010_x64.zip) installed and then I attempted to install SSIS Attunity Connectors as explained on this [post](http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/jonathoneveoconnor/post/Setup-Of-Oracle-Attunity-Connectors). It's supposed that after the installation I would see the components on the SSIS toolbox (Data Flow section) but no matter what I do they simply don't show up.

I can successfully connect to oracle server using the component we have always used.

My SSIS projects target version is SQL Server 2016. Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. My OS: Windows 10 Enterprise.

I tried to install v4 32-bit version of the attunity connector and it did not work, I also tried to install v3 64-bit version of the attunity connector and the installation failed because I don't have SQL Server 2014 installed only 2016, which is why I'm supposed to use v4 64-bits.

Any advice from anybody who had an issue like this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need both x86 and x64 versions of the Oracle clients.
And you should install both [4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52950) and [5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55179) x64 (x86 will be added automatically) versions of Attunity connectors.
After that you should be able (almost guaranteed) to see Attunity connectors in the SSIS Toolbox in VS2015.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! After installing v5.0 it worked. I did not know there was a 5.0 version and it's difficult to look for that since I was installing 4.0 that is the one for SQL Server 2016 and that's the version I have installed. I read 5.0 documentation and it says it is for SQL Server 2017 SSIS. Anyway, issue is solved now and I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you too. Developing at VS 2015 with SSDT 17.* is a pain in the donkey. Almost all features aren't working normally from the scratch.